# Htaccess redirect loop for Concrete downloads, difficulty level: wordpress also in the mix

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, concrete5, concrete

I have a WordPress install in my root web folder. It is using the standard WordPress .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

For Reasons I cannot change, there used to be a Concrete5 install in the root. It has been moved to a subfolder called "form".

WordPress and Concrete are happily coexisting, with 1 exception: I need previous Concrete downloads to redirect to the new location. And what I am trying in my .htaccess file is not working:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/download_file/force/(.*) /form/index.php/download_file/force/$1
```

I am trying to move from this:

```
http://example.com/index.php/download_file/force/623/145/
```

To this:

```
http://example.com/form/index.php/download_file/force/623/145/
```

I am currently getting a redirect loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rewrite pattern must start with a **^**

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/download_file/force/(.*) /form/index.php/download_file/force/$1
```

Otherwise the redirect destination also matches the pattern **/index.php/download_file/force/(.*)** and causes a redirect loop

Comment: Of course. Ugh. I am used to page by page redirects and not this type. Thank you!